# java File.separator becomes "%" in path of the File on Windows

Tags: java, windows, file

I try to read files from the resources folder. The problem is, that the `File.separator` turns into a "`%"` on Windows.

```
String inputFilesFolder = "input_files" + File.separator;
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(inputFilesFolder + "filename").getFile());
```

The `inputFilesFolder` is still fine (`input_files/`), but after creating the file `file.getPath()` becomes `D:\blabla\input_files%filename`.

Then I try to read the file, but I get a FileNotFoundException (big surprise).
What's wrong here?

Comment: Please fix your code the way you actually have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(inputFilesFolder + filename).toURI());
```

Comment: You can't load resource from a package as File :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean...  but yes it is possible.

Comment: Yes? so you also can list files in you app package, or modify them?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki If the file are exploded ① *Yup*. ② *Nope*. :)

Answer (score 5):

File.separator is a file system thing. When you're using classLoader.getResource() always use forward slash as the name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name.

[See Javadoc for getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Comment: Good hint. Or as my prof used to say: "Use the source"

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 String inputFilesFolder = "input_files" + File.separator;
 File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(inputFilesFolder + filename).toString());
```

Comment: getResource() returns a URL, and File does not have a constructor which accepts it.

Comment: @vargen_ use toString() so that file will use File(String) constructor